# No SizeChanged event while resizing snapped view

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm stuck with some strange behavior. My windows store app (targeted to 8.0) does not receive SizeChanged events while I resize snapped view. App just stay in same size, just centered in view. Did I miss something?

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard behavior for Windows 8.0 apps in Windows 8.1 environment.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.0, you cannot resize snapview. The only event is a change in snap state.

> Here's the official code: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Developing-Snap-View-for-057348a0

Basically, use the built-in LayoutAwarePage.

Here's the technique when you start with Windows 8.1: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html

Comment: LayoutAwarePage works in the same way as mine: http://i.imgur.com/7GWXPHc.png (in the simulator under windows 8.1)